# Why trending line of scatter plot doesn't match given equation?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some sample data, I draw a trending line which gives me equation as well. But I found that the trending line sometimes isn't trustworthy at all.

**The trending line graph doesn't match the equation!**

I think that's unacceptable and totally out of my expectation. Why is it?

---

Sample data:

```
count(x)    runtime(y)
1000         0.1
2000         0.8
4000         6.4
8000         51.1
```

How to reproduce it: Draw a scatter plot, add a trending line, choose Exponential. Then try to calculate by the given equation, when `x` = `4000`, `7000`, `8000`. And you can see `y` doesn't match the graph at all.

---

fileLink: https://anonfile.com/A4m0F7lbb3/sheet1_-_copy_xlsx

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Got same result, my friend. They're the same equation I think.

Comment: You are correct. I can't explain it either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

The problem is the equation has some rounding in it. If you  right-click on it and select `Format trendline label`:

[image]

You can add decimal places:

[image]

and get a more precise result:

[image]

Comment: You are a genius!